# Reverse Direction of a specific row in a grid

Tags: html, css, grid, responsive, direction

I am trying to reverse the direction of a specific row in a grid when on mobile.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="project"></div>
    <div class="project"></div>
    <div class="project"></div>
    <div class="project"></div>
    <div class="project"></div>
    <div class="project"></div>
    <div class="project"></div>
    <div class="project"></div>
</div>
```

The goal is to have the second div appear before the first when the browser meets a specific media query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`order` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order).

If you set `display: flex;` on `.wrapper` and set `order: -1` on the 2nd `div` inside `.wrapper`, it will display first.

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper div:nth-of-type(2) {
  order: -1;
}
```

Now, put that inside a [Media Query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), and you can restrict that behaviour to mobile.

Here's a [CodePen example](https://codepen.io/mrintoul/pen/XOymdx).